# Расстановка приоритетов с помощью кучи Python

Tags: python

Код должен формировать словарь `priority` и добавлять приоритет значениям словаря с помощью кучи. А по определённому запросу необходимо вернуть наибольшее по приоритету и **по номеру** значение

Я проверяю, что в начальном запросе `promt`.
Если номер задачи `'task'` - я добавляю её название `task`  и её номер `task_is` в словарь, а после даю этой задаче соответствующий приоритет `pri`, формируя макс-кучу через отрицательное значение приоритета `-1 * pri`.
Когда поступает команда `'take'`,  я удаляю максимальное значение и возвращаю его в виде `f-строки`:

```
f'Задача {num_is} с приоритетом {-1 * pri_is}'
```

Но при этом не выполняется условие, что при запросе `'take'` должно возвращаться не только наибольший приоритет, но и **номер**.
Не могу понять как отсортировать по данному условию при запросе, подскажите, где заблуждаюсь

Код:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush, heapify


heap = []
heapify(heap)

priority = {}

while (promt := input()) != 'end':

    if 'task' in promt:
        task = promt.split(',')[0]
        task_is = int(task.split()[1])
        pri = int(promt.split(',')[1])

        priority[task] = task_is

        heappush(heap, (priority[task], -1 * pri))

    elif 'take' in promt:
        pop_is = heappop(heap)
        num_is = pop_is[0]
        pri_is = pop_is[1]

        print(f'Задача {num_is} с приоритетом {-1 * pri_is}')
```

Входящие данные:

```
task 101,5
task 10,5
task 10,3
task 1,6
task 2,2
take
take
task 10,10
take
take
end
```

Итог:

```
Correct output:
Задача 1 с приоритетом 6
Задача 101 с приоритетом 5
Задача 10 с приоритетом 10
Задача 10 с приоритетом 5

Your code output:
Задача 1 с приоритетом 6
Задача 2 с приоритетом 2
Задача 10 с приоритетом 10
Задача 10 с приоритетом 5
```

Comment: @MBo
 
Реализуйте очередь с приоритетами на базе кучи с максимумом в вершине – самый большой элемент всегда идет первее. Если делаете без кучи – имейте в виду, что сортировать нужно одновременно по приоритету и номеру.

Вашей программе поступают на вход команды:

`task` <номер задачи>, <приоритет> – добавить задачу;
`take` – взять задачу в работу, вывести в консоль лог (Задача <номер задачи> с приоритетом <приоритет>);
`end` – завершить выполнение программы.

Comment: @MBo
Тут условие задачи не совсем удачное, получается, что значение ключа и есть ключ. То есть, если ключ равен `Task 101`, то значение равно `101`
Я правильно понял Ваше замечание?

Comment: @MBo
Так в том то и вопрос, возможно ли проводить сравнение одновременно и по ключу и по приоритету?

Comment: Ох, я не увидел, что у вас  task 10,10 вставляется в середине работы, так что мои комменты не к месту, удаляю.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from heapq import heappop, heappush, heapify

heap = []
heapify(heap)

priority = {}

while True:
    promt = input()
    if 'task' in promt:
        task = promt.split(',')[0]
        task_is = int(task.split()[1])
        pri = int(promt.split(',')[1])

        priority[task] = task_is

        heappush(heap, (-pri,-task_is))
        

    elif 'take' in promt:
        pop_is = heappop(heap)
        num_is = -pop_is[1]
        pri_is = -pop_is[0]

        print(f'Задача {num_is} с приоритетом {pri_is}')
        
    elif 'end' in promt:
        break
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]